# PyInstaller gerando erro para importar a biblioteca numpy

Tags: python, dll, numpy, pyinstaller

Boa tarde,

Estou criando um projeto em python, e preciso obter um executavel .exe para rodar em qualquer windows sem ter o python instalado. Porém, o que ocorre é que quando eu abro o executável gerado na pasta build\compilando (compilando.exe) ele retorna o erro:

```
Error loading Python DLL'C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando\build\compilando\python37.dll'.

LoadLibrary: NÒo foi possÝvel encontrar o m¾dulo especificado.
```

O código funciona perfeitamente em python, e possui a biblioteca numpy instalada, tanto pelo pip, quanto pelo pip3:

O que preciso fazer para o código funcionar?

Obrigado.

**Codigo:**

```
import numpy
```

**Arquivo .spec:**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-


block_cipher = None



a = Analysis(['compilando.py'],

             pathex=['C:\\Users\\enzo\\Desktop\\Compilando'],

             binaries=[],

             datas=[],

             hiddenimports=[],

             hookspath=[],

             runtime_hooks=[],

             excludes=[],

             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,

             win_private_assemblies=False,

             cipher=block_cipher,

             noarchive=False)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,

             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,

          a.scripts,

          [],

          exclude_binaries=True,

          name='compilando',

          debug=False,

          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,

          strip=False,

          upx=True,

          console=True )

coll = COLLECT(exe,

           a.binaries+[('zipcontainer.dll','C:\\Windows\\System32\\zipcontainer.dll','BINARY')],

           a.zipfiles,

           a.datas,

           strip=None,

           upx=True,

           name='compilando')
```

**Output CMD na criacao do arquivo .exe:**

```
(ENV) C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando>pyinstaller compilando.spec

69 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4

69 INFO: Python: 3.7.2rc1

69 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0

69 INFO: UPX is not available.

69 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths

['C:\\Users\\enzo\\Desktop\\Compilando', 'C:\\Users\\enzo\\Desktop\\Compilando']

69 INFO: checking Analysis

69 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent

69 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...

69 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...

69 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...

3167 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc

3183 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable

  required by c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python.exe

3214 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python.exe

3230 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python.exe

3268 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python.exe

3299 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python.exe

3330 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python.exe

3368 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\vcruntime140.dll

3399 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\vcruntime140.dll

3430 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\vcruntime140.dll

3462 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\vcruntime140.dll

3484 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\vcruntime140.dll

3662 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3684 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3715 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3747 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3784 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3816 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3831 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3869 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3900 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3916 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3963 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

3985 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

4001 INFO: Caching module hooks...

4001 INFO: Analyzing compilando.py

4854 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils

4854 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\enzo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\distutils'

6339 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site

6339 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\enzo\\desktop\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'

7555 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves

9885 INFO: Loading module hooks...

9885 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...

9885 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...

9986 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...

9986 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...

10070 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...

10070 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...

10627 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'

10692 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'

1**** INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...

1**** INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.py"...

1**** INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...

11263 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...

11263 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...

11263 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...

11294 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs

11325 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...

11325 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'

11325 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'

11341 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries

20144 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_contextvars.pyd

20164 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_decimal.pyd

20194 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_decimal.pyd

20214 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_decimal.pyd

20234 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_decimal.pyd

20264 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_decimal.pyd

20284 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_decimal.pyd

20312 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_decimal.pyd

20334 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd

20364 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd

20393 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd

20415 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_queue.pyd

20453 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd

20485 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_ssl.pyd

20505 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_ssl.pyd

20535 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_ssl.pyd

20553 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd

20585 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd

20600 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd

20631 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd

20654 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd

20685 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd

20700 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd

20732 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd

20754 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd

20785 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd

20816 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd

20832 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd

20854 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd

20885 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd

20917 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_lzma.pyd

20932 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_lzma.pyd

20970 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_socket.pyd

21001 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\_socket.pyd

21032 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\select.pyd

21055 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_fpumode.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21086 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback_c.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21117 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback_c.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21133 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback_c.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21155 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback_c.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21186 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\messagestream.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21202 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\messagestream.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21233 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\messagestream.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21255 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\messagestream.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21286 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21302 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21333 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21355 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21387 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21402 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21433 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21456 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21471 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21503 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21534 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21556 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21572 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21603 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21618 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21656 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21672 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack_lite.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21703 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack_lite.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21734 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21756 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21788 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21819 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21850 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

21872 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll

21904 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll

21935 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll

21957 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll

22601 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

22619 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

22650 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

22666 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

22697 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

22751 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

22778 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

22798 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

22819 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

28454 INFO: Looking for eggs

28454 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\scripts\python37.dll

28462 INFO: Found binding redirects:

[]

28472 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando\build\compilando\warn-compilando.txt

28572 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando\build\compilando\xref-compilando.html

28603 INFO: checking PYZ

28603 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent

28603 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando\build\compilando\PYZ-00.pyz

29657 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando\build\compilando\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.

29682 INFO: checking PKG

29682 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent

29682 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg

29713 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.

29713 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe

29713 INFO: checking EXE

29713 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent

29713 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc

29729 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando\build\compilando\compilando.exe

29829 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

29829 INFO: checking COLLECT

29829 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent

29829 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc

31508 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.


(ENV) C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando>cd dist


(ENV) C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando\dist>cd compilando


(ENV) C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando\dist\compilando>compilando.exe

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "compilando.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module

    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

  File "site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 151, in <module>

  File "c:\users\enzo\desktop\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module

    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

  File "site-packages\numpy\ctypeslib.py", line 369, in <module>

  File "site-packages\numpy\ctypeslib.py", line 358, in _get_typecodes

  File "site-packages\numpy\ctypeslib.py", line 358, in <dictcomp>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._dtype_ctypes'

[4732] Failed to execute script compilando
```

O código foi rodado em windows 8.1 e windows 10 (diferentes pcs) obtendo os mesmos resultados.

Estou usando um ambiente virtual (ENV)

Numpy instalado atraves do pip3

Python 3.7.x

Answer (score 0):

Bom, depois de um tempo consegui achar algo por aí e descobri que é simplesmente necessário instalar a biblioteca https://pypi.org/project/ctypes/ e importa-la no comeco do código com `import ctypes`.